# mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)

Tags: android

I ve written code to craete new folders in internal sd like this...

```
File MainDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/");
    if(!MainDirectory.exists()){
        File DBDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/database");
        File ProPicDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/profilephoto");
        File ProPicTempDirecctory=new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/profilephoto/temp");
        File ReportPicDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/reportphoto");
        File ReportThumbPicDirectory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/app/reportphoto/thumb");


        MainDirectory.mkdirs();
        DBDirectory.mkdir();
        ProPicDirectory.mkdir();
        ProPicTempDirecctory.mkdir();
        ReportPicDirectory.mkdir();
        ReportThumbPicDirectory.mkdir();
    }
```

This code worked perfectly on two three times, even when i delete the the folders via file manager and deleteting the app , when i reinstalled it worked correctly. After the third time this error occurs....

```
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app/database
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app/profilephoto
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app/profilephoto/temp
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app/reportphoto
I/System.out: mkdir failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy) path = /mnt/sdcard/app/reportphoto/thumb
```

How can i resolve this issue.?

Comment: What do your purpose??

Comment: are you deleting your folders in your code anywhere?

Comment: No... am deleted the folders via file explorer

Comment: Terrible that you use all those hard coded paths. Further you should not blindly call mkdir or mkdirs but only if the directory does not exist. Check with .exists(). Further you should check the return value of mkdir(s) as it might fail to create the directory. If so then do not continue but display a toast and return.

Comment: @greenapps Try to stay on topic (please?)

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Where are you talking about? You can clearly see that mkdir() fails. One should not call mkdir() if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

```
 File MainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/app");
    if(!MainDirectory.exists()){
        File DBDirectory = new File(MainDirectory+"/database");
        File ProPicDirectory = new File(MainDirectory+"/profilephoto");
        File ProPicTempDirecctory = new File(ProPicDirectory+"/temp");
        File ReportPicDirectory = new File(MainDirectory+"/reportphoto");
        File ReportThumbPicDirectory = new File(ReportPicDirectory+"/thumb");


        MainDirectory.mkdirs();
        DBDirectory.mkdir();
        ProPicDirectory.mkdir();
        ProPicTempDirecctory.mkdir();
        ReportPicDirectory.mkdir();
        ReportThumbPicDirectory.mkdir();
    }
```

It is working fine for me.

Hope it helps .

Comment: No still the same

Comment: Hey are you deleting your folders anywhere?

Comment: if yes, this problem arises when the system is trying to open an existing file again(If you have deleted it) So what you gotta do is just renaming the folder before deleting . If you rename the folder or file before you delete it, there is no chance for the system to try to open an existing file again or an open file which you want to save again (or something like this).

Comment: @pulkit i do not believe a word of this.

Comment: @pulkit I confirm your idea worked for me on LG-D855. I failed to re-create a folder with the same name after deleting if the folder was not empty before removing. But if I rename it with a random name and then remove - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you had the permissions of writing and reading storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

check again.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is the file or directory is locked by the system or some other process.

How did I come to this conclusion?

Well, in the previous build of my application, I was creating a hidden directory at the root directory containing data files (including media files). Then I decided not to make it hidden. All of a sudden my test devices started crashing. I changed the folder back to hidden and it worked again.

So, if there isn't a process accessing the directory, it's probably the Android system scanning for media files and doing Google knows what. Perhaps a `.nomedia` file could fix this (I didn't try) but then again if you have no control over the resource you're out of luck.